# Why could I recover the permission of root mount point after I execute 'sudo chmod -x /'

Tags: linux

I executed the command 'sudo chmod -x /' in terminal emulator(running on X) out of curiosity. And found out that I couldn't do any more except switched to console and logged in with root user and changed the permission back. But how could I manage to make it since I didn't have execution permission of the root directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the root user on Linux possesses a capability (`CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH`) that gives search permission on every directory, even if the filesystem says it's -x.